# Clicking on nav bar works. But HTML href is pointing to something else

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to collect some metadata on the market analysis reports in [BCC Research](https://www.bccresearch.com/). They have data on different [topics](https://www.bccresearch.com/market-research) such as Advanced Materials, Biotechnology,etc.

If you go under a topic, say [Advanced Materials](https://www.bccresearch.com/market-research/advanced-materials), the reports are spread across a number of nav pages at the bottom.

When I click on say a nav page, say number 2, the page "refreshes" by scrolling up. This naturally loads more results onto the screen. Now the problem is, when I check the link using **href** (an example is, https://www.bccresearch.com/market-research/advanced-materials/page/2) of the nav page, it takes me back to the main page for the topic, instead of the second page.

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

EDIT: Screenshots of the nav page source before and after I click a nav page link.
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFwzP.jpg)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8v5b.jpg)

Comment: When I click a different page, the URL doesn't change for me.  How do you know that https://www.bccresearch.com/market-research/advanced-materials/page/2 is a valid URL?  Where is that coming from?

Comment: @LoganPhillips I have added the before after picture in the post. Please refer to them and thank you for the help.

Comment: Please include your code with the question. [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is using POST requests to update the page content rather than navigate away

The links to send requests to are of format:

https://www.bccresearch.com/default/index/category/page/3/cod/advanced-materials/rnge/25

where there is a page number e.g. 3 and a results per page number e.g. 25.

These are not urls you can visit in your browser.

When you click on the nav icons the POST request is made for the nav icon whose class has become `active`.

If you use a method like selenium, you can automate the clicking of these links which will generate the POST requests and you can scrape content from the updated page.

With selenium you could set the results count to 100 per page. Calculate the number of pages by dividing total results count/ results count page (and rounding up). Then click next chevron to move through all pages

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import math
import time

url = 'https://www.bccresearch.com/market-research/advanced-materials'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a")))
#switch to 100 results per page
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.itperpg:last-child').click()

#calculate number of pages
results_count = int(re.search('(\d+)',driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#publishedrpt h1').text).group())
results_per_page = 100
num_pages = math.ceil(results_count / results_per_page)
print(num_pages)

#click next button through all pages

for page in range(num_pages):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label=Next]"))).click()
    time.sleep(3) #replace this with better condition based wait

    #do something with page
```

Comment: This fixes it. Thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: As a follow up, I was wondering if the same could be done with the help of **requests**

Comment: I’ll have a look tomorrow. Did you try using dev tools to examine the POST xhrs?